# Split and Combine Date

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write a python script that will compare dates from two different pages. The format of date in one page is Oct 03 2016 whereas on other page is (10/3/2016). My goal is to compare these two dates. I was able to convert Oct to 10 but don't know how to make it 10/3/2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to convert your string to `datetime` object and then compare both. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date1 = datetime.strptime('Oct 03 2016', '%b %d %Y')
>>> date2 = datetime.strptime('10/3/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> date1 == date2
True
```

Further, you may convert this`datetime` object to your custom format using [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) as:

```
>>> date1.strftime('%d * %B * %Y')
'03 * October * 2016'
```

List of all the directives usable for formatting the string are available at the `strftime` link I mentioned above.

Comment: @Quadri I am trying to use your answer but I am getting an error "TypeError: must be string, not list". What should I do? I am trying to use variable in place of date **date1 = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y')**

Comment: The value you need to pass as `date` should be of `str` ,  but based on the error you are getting, you are passing the object of `list` type.

Comment: Exactly, how can I do that? I mean I want something like this **date = "Oct 07 2016" date1 = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y') **

Comment: You are using `strptime` but you need to use `strftime`.

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'list'. When using strftime?

Answer (score 6):

You should really be using the `dateutil` library for this.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser 
>>> first_date = dateutil.parser.parse('Oct 03 2016')
>>> second_date = dateutil.parser.parse('10/3/2016')
>>> first_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 0, 0)
>>> second_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 0, 0)
>>> first_date == second_date
True
>>>
```

Comment: Yes. You need to install it.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri whoops. Yeah that should be `import dateutil.parser`. I usually retype everything in the shell once I fiddle around with it so I can easily copy and paste the answer.

Comment: *Note:* There will be chances of ambiguity with `parser` for the date as `3/5/2016`. Which is date and month? `dateutil.parser.parse('3/5/2016')` will return `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 5, 0, 0)` considering it in `M/D/YYYY` format.

Comment: You can pass a boolean for the `dayfirst` keyword argument to specify the behavior you want.

Comment: I think you should probably mention this with the answer for others looking at it in the future :)